# C# Generic Abstract Class - There is no implicit reference conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, generics

I am having an issue with some code that used to compile and now does not (after an upgrade to MVC 4). The code is in a class that inherits from an abstract base class that has some generics. I've searched all over and everyone's question/answer is close to what I'm trying to do but not a match so please let me know if I just totally suck at Google or what. Anywhere here is the basic implementation I'm working with.

```
namespace Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses
{
    public abstract class HomeViewModel<T> where T: HomeAddressViewModel
    {
        public abstract T AddressViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses
{
    public class HomeAddressViewModel
    {
    }
}

namespace Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses
{
    public class SingleFamilyAddressViewModel : HomeAddressViewModel
    {
    }
}

namespace Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Enrolments
{
    public class SingleFamilyEnrollmentViewModel : HomeViewModel<SingleFamilyAddressViewModel>
    {
        public override SingleFamilyAddressViewModel AddressViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It seems obvious to me I'm somehow violating the constraint but I don't see how? Is it the inheritance of the HomeAddressViewModel in the SingleFamilyAddressViewModel? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit: The actual error message I get at compile is Error "The type 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses.SingleFamilyAddressViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses.HomeViewModel'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses.SingleFamilyAddressViewModel' to 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses.HomeAddressViewModel'."**

Edit 2: I have included the namespaces and have triple checked for a duplicate class names. I have taken this code out and created a seperate project and of course the code compiles like it used to so I'm not sure why the upgrade to mvc 4 would have changed that.

Comment: Please show the exact error message within your question, and the code that generates that error. The code you've provided so far compiles without any errors.

Comment: Here is the actual error message I am getting.

The type 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses.SingleFamilyAddressViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses.HomeViewModel<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses.SingleFamilyAddressViewModel' to 'Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses.HomeAddressViewModel'.

That is the code that generates the error. It does not compile. I stripped out the non relevant properties and fields. I don't understand why this isn't compiling.

Comment: In the question, please... along with the code.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post to include the error message. Thanks.

Comment: Then the code you've provided isn't the code you're using. The code you've provided works fine. I suggest you check that `SingleFamilyAddressViewModel` really derives from `Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses.HomeAddressViewModel`.

Comment: I assure you that those are my exact class definitions. I removed the non relevant properties but that is exactly what the code looks like. I can zip up the classes if you would like to see them.

Comment: Well that's *not* exactly what the code looks like, because you haven't included the relevant namespace declarations, for a start. I suggest you try compiling *just* the code you've provided, in a separate project - it'll work fine. At that point, you need to work out the difference between what you've provided and what you've actually got. (For example, do you have two different classes called `HomeAddressViewModel`? You've got two different namespaces involved here, after all - `Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.AbstractClasses` and `Site.ViewModels.EasyEnrol.Addresses`.)

Comment: Fair enough. I have added the namespaces to the class definitions. That code is 100% what I am working with and you are correct that it compiles... it just doesn't compile in my upgraded MVC 4 app.

Answer (score 0):

So I have no idea what was causing the issue since by all accounts the code should have compiled. I ended up reverting from source control to some code from yesterday (mostly bin and some JS changes) and that seems to have fixed the issue. I don't have enough rep to up vote but thanks Jon Skeet for taking the time to help me look into this matter. I really appreciate your time.